# 6j symbols trouble when irrep multiplicity >1

Tags: rt.representation-theory

With my uncanny guessing abilities :-) I finally derived the size of the vector space
where a n-valent node of a graph, edge-colored with the irreps $R_k, 1\le{k}\le{n}$ "lives". (I.e. in how many linear independent diagrams you decompose it, see e.g. "Birdtracks".) It's (heavy notation abuse) $\sharp{(1)}\in\Pi^\bigotimes_n{R_k}$ or, since this likely causes a syntax crash, in words: Just tensor multiply all the $R_k$ and count how many copies of the trivial irrep $1$ you find in the product. (Can you verify my finding?)

Especially, for n=3 this means (excuse my ASCII) a triangle =|>- reduces either to 6j* >- 
or zero if >- is inadmissible (the triple product doesn't contain $1$). But haaaalt!
Assume all irreps here are $(1,1)$ from $A_2$. $(1,1)\bigotimes(1,1)$ contains TWO copies of $(1,1)$ and thus the triple product two $1$, i.e. there exist two linear independent graphs with three open ends.

Which means =|>- should be something like 6j* >- + 6j* >- ...but there are no two >-, you can only build this one acyclic graph! On the other hand: 6j symbols being undefined due to multiplicity >1 - I would have heard of that. Where is the hole in my logic?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your logic. This is something you have to live with.

Comment: I've always found 6j symbols when there's multiplicities very confusing.

Comment: 6j symbols should really be called 6j+4k symbols, where the 4 k's index bases of the trivalent vertex spaces.  It's a weird, special fact about SU(2) that you can ignore the k's.  In general this is almost never the case.

Comment:  @Kevin (or anybody else) - do you know a good reference to start? (From my spectroscopic work, I'm accustomed to additional quantum numbers, like "seniority" or an additional counter index for equal $^{2S+1}L_J$ terms, but luckily, I'm exclusively working in SU(2) :-)

Comment: Not to bump a dead thread, but in case it is still needed and for anyone else who may run across this, [On Arithmetic Modular Categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2229) gives a through description and derivation for moving between 10j-Symbols and fusion categories.